# Spotfire - Sum() over

Tags: sum, calculated-columns, spotfire

I'm trying to sum the values in column INDICATOR for the last 30 days from DATE, by account.

My expression is: Sum([INDICATOR]) over (Intersect([id],LastPeriods(30,[DATE]))) but the results are not accurate.

Any help is appreciated.

Sample data below:

```
    DATE    30DAYSBACK  ID  INDICATOR   RUNNING30   EXPECTED
    3/2/16  2/1/16  ABC 1   3   3
    3/2/16  2/1/16  ABC 1   3   3
    3/2/16  2/1/16  ABC 1   3   3  
    3/7/16  2/6/16  ABC 1   7   7
    3/7/16  2/6/16  ABC 1   7   7
    3/7/16  2/6/16  ABC 1   7   7
    3/7/16  2/6/16  ABC 1   7   7
    3/8/16  2/7/16  ABC 1   10  10
    3/8/16  2/7/16  ABC 1   10  10
    3/8/16  2/7/16  ABC 1   10  10
    3/10/16 2/9/16  ABC 1   12  12
    3/10/16 2/9/16  ABC 1   12  12
    3/14/16 2/13/16 ABC 1   13  13
    3/15/16 2/14/16 ABC 1   14  14
    3/16/16 2/15/16 ABC 1   15  15
    3/21/16 2/20/16 ABC 1   16  16
    3/22/16 2/21/16 ABC 1   17  17
    3/23/16 2/22/16 ABC 1   19  19
    3/23/16 2/22/16 ABC 1   19  19
    3/25/16 2/24/16 ABC 1   20  20
    3/29/16 2/28/16 ABC 1   22  22
    3/29/16 2/28/16 ABC 1   22  22
    3/30/16 2/29/16 ABC 1   27  27
    3/30/16 2/29/16 ABC 1   27  27
    3/30/16 2/29/16 ABC 1   27  27
    3/30/16 2/29/16 ABC 1   27  27
    3/30/16 2/29/16 ABC 1   27  27
    3/31/16 3/1/16  ABC 1   29  29
    3/31/16 3/1/16  ABC 1   29  29
    4/1/16  3/2/16  ABC 1   31  31
    4/1/16  3/2/16  ABC 1   31  31
    4/4/16  3/5/16  ABC 1   32  29
    4/5/16  3/6/16  ABC 1   33  30
    4/13/16 3/14/16 ABC 1   34  27
    4/13/16 3/14/16 ABC 1   34  27
    4/13/16 3/14/16 ABC 1   34  27
    4/13/16 3/14/16 ABC 1   34  27
    4/15/16 3/16/16 ABC 1   35  24
    4/20/16 3/21/16 ABC 1   31  26
    4/20/16 3/21/16 ABC 1   31  26
    4/20/16 3/21/16 ABC 1   31  26
    4/25/16 3/26/16 ABC 1   31  25
    4/25/16 3/26/16 ABC 1   31  25
    4/25/16 3/26/16 ABC 1   31  25
    4/26/16 3/27/16 ABC 1   31  26
    4/27/16 3/28/16 ABC 1   34  29
    4/27/16 3/28/16 ABC 1   34  29
    4/27/16 3/28/16 ABC 1   34  29
    4/27/16 3/28/16 ABC 1   34  29
    4/28/16 3/29/16 ABC 1   35  30
```

Comment: Can you attach a sample data set?

Comment: Thanks for the data set, however it's missing the `[INDICATOR]` column

Comment: Sorry! [INDICATOR] is effectively just a value of 1 straight down. (Mislabeled above... seen as 'IDENTIFIER' above.)

Comment: Your formula is working correctly. The problem you are running into is that you don't have a row for every day. It is doing the `SUM()` correctly for the past 30 `PERIODS` based on the sorting of your data when you load it into Spotfire.

It's hard to suggest an alternative because I don't know what the end goal really is. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: What I'm looking to get is a sum of indicators on an account that occurred in the past 30 days. So, for example, if I'm looking at 4/28/2016, I want to sum the indicators beginning and including 3/29/2016 (30 day lookback) to 4/28/2016 (inclusive).

Comment: I attempted a another expression but it is returning a value of 50 straight down.      case  when DateDiff("day",Max([Date]) OVER (Intersect([ID],Intersect(AllPrevious([Date]),[ID]))),[30daysback])<31 then 
     Sum([INDICATOR]) over ([ID])
else 0
end

Comment: That happened because you are taking the max date for the column, so essentially it will always be true and add up everything. I'm still thinking of a way to accomplish your goal but haven't figured out a way around not having a row for every day.

Answer (score 0):

I wan't able to determine a suitable solution within Spotfire.  However, I was able to write some R code that allows for the Date and Indicator columns to be passed to it, sums the indicator for the past 30 days, and then returns this as a column.

Here is the code:

```
record.date <-as.Date(date.column, "%m/%d/%Y")
indicator.vector <- indicator.column

num.entry <- length(record.date)
running.thirty <- vector(length=num.entry)
count <- 0

for(i in 1:num.entry){
  date.test <- record.date[i]
  for(j in 1:num.entry){
    if(record.date[j] >= date.test-30 ){
      if(record.date[j] <= date.test){
        count <- count + indicator.vector[j]
      }
    }
  }
  running.thirty[i] <- count
  count <- 0  
}

output<-running.thirty
```

Use Tools >> Register Data Function

(1) Insert the script

(2) Create the two input parameters:

[input parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpoJi.jpg)

(3) Create the output parameter:

[output parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EDd5.jpg)

NOTE:  I think there are some errors in your expected values near the end of your data set.